# If someone is a Canadian permanent resident, can they pay tuition fees at the domestic rate?

Tags: canada, tuition

Every Canadian tertiary institution maintains different rates for domestic students and international students for the payment of tuition fees.

If someone has a Canadian PR (Permanent Residency), can he pay tuition fees at domestic rates? Or, is this facility offered only for full citizens?

Comment: I started as an international student, and got my PR while in school. The moment I got my PR I stopped paying the international fees. Of course, this could depend on the University

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are, at least in [Ontario](https://registrar.ontariotechu.ca/fees-and-payment/tuition-and-fees/international-student-tuition/eligibility-for-domestic-fees.php), [Quebec](https://www.mcgill.ca/student-accounts/tuition-fees/general-tuition-and-fees-information/fees-residency), [BC](https://you.ubc.ca/financial-planning/tuition-fees/), [Alberta](https://www.ualberta.ca/registrar/costs-tuition-fees/undergraduate-tuition/fall-winter-tuition-for-canadian-citizens-and-permanent-residents.html), and [Manitoba](https://www.umanitoba.ca/admissions/undergraduate-admissions/tuition-estimates).

This covers [90%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_of_Canada_by_province_and_territory) of the population of Canada, and I'm sure you could find the regulations for the other provinces and Yukon (there are no universities in NWT and Nunavut) if that's where your institution is with a quick search like I did.

Comment: Quebec  residents must also provide proof of residency *in Quebec*.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Only if they want the Quebec rate, rather than the Canadian rate.

Comment: @PeterK. well I just learned something.  All I remember are the student protests from many (20?) years ago.

Comment: @PeterK. According to the page I linked, you have to provide proof of either.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Right: But the implication of the original comment was that Quebec residents have to provide residency in Quebec. That is not true, unless they want the Quebec rate. If they're happy paying double, then they only need to show that they're Canadian.

Comment: @PeterK. Oh, I suppose.